# How can I close the inflated layer?

Tags: java, android

I made the close button on the inflated layer. And I want to close this inflated layer when I click that button. How can I solve this problem

I used `Rl.setVisibility(View.GONE);`
But When I restart this method it's not working properly.
(different layer comes out...all the buttons are not working)

```
public void layer(){
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final RelativeLayout Rl = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_bookmark, null);
    //Rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#99000000"));
    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramRl = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
            (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT);

    addContentView(Rl, paramRl);
    final String current_url = webView.getUrl();
    final Button btn_add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    final Button btn_out = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_out);

    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_input);
    editText.setText(current_url);
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_bookmark);
    final ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.menu_bookmark_row, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (editText.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                String inputStr = editText.getText().toString();
                arrayList.add(inputStr);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
    btn_out.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // <--I NEED HELP!!!!!
        }
    });
```

Comment: do you want to remove your list item ? by click ?

Comment: I don't want to remove it!! just close the layer for a while so i can use it again.

Comment: like hide ? but fully hide as item ?

Comment: Yes, i want to hide it

Comment: first thing why not you are using recycler view

Comment: oh...i didn't know about recycler view....... but is there any way to hide the inflated layer?

Answer (score 0):

parentLinearLayout.removeView((View) v.getParent());
https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/basics/dynamically-add-and-remove-views-in-android/